# How to correctly re-write static call to the OOP way?

Tags: 9

1. Calling static function **entityQuery()**:

> `$query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')->condition('type','article')->execute();`

2. Calling static function **loadMultiple()**:

> `$nodes = Node::loadMultiple($nids);`

Thanks!

Comment: Inside where exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends from where the code is executed. In a function that doesn't have the dependency injection as one of its parameters, the only way to use the dependency injection container is via the `\Drupal` class.
This means that, for example in a hook implementation, `\Drupal::entityQuery()` will be always called. When loading nodes, you could use either `Node::loadMultiple()` or the following code, which essentially is a simplified version of the code used by [`EntityBase::loadMultiple()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityBase.php/function/EntityBase%3A%3AloadMultiple/9.3.x).

```php
$entity_type_manager = \Drupal::entityTypeManager();
$storage = $entity_type_manager->getStorage('node');
$nodes = $storage->loadMultiple($nids);
```

In a static method that doesn't that doesn't have the dependency injection as one of its parameters, the only use the dependency injection container is via the `\Drupal` class. For example, this is done in Drupal core with [`ContentEntityBase::create()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21ContentEntityBase.php/function/ContentEntityBase%3A%3Acreate/9.3.x).

```php
public static function create(array $values = []) {
  $entity_type_repository = \Drupal::service('entity_type.repository');
  $entity_type_manager = \Drupal::entityTypeManager();
  $class_name = static::class;
  $storage = $entity_type_manager->getStorage($entity_type_repository
    ->getEntityTypeFromClass($class_name));

  if ($storage instanceof BundleEntityStorageInterface && ($bundle = $storage->getBundleFromClass($class_name))) {
    $values[$storage->getEntityType()->getKey('bundle')] = $bundle;
  }
  return $storage->create($values);
}
```

In code I wrote, I would verify the method is effectively called statically; if it's not, I would rewrite the code to use the dependency injection container, when possible.

In services, their dependencies will be passed to the classes that implement the service, so the code would become the following one, where `$this->entityTypeManager` is the property set from the class constructor, which contains the entity type manager.

```php
$query = $this->entityTypeManager->getStorage('node')->getQuery();
```

```php
$storage = $this->entityTypeManager->getStorage('node');
$nodes = $storage->loadMultiple($nids);
```

The same is done from classes that implement [`ContainerInjectionInterface`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21DependencyInjection%21ContainerInjectionInterface.php/interface/ContainerInjectionInterface/9.3.x) (or other interfaces like [`ContainerFactoryPluginInterface`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Plugin%21ContainerFactoryPluginInterface.php/interface/ContainerFactoryPluginInterface/9.3.x) for plugins). The difference is that their dependencies aren't defined in a file like services, but injected from their `create()` method.

As for calling a static method, there isn't anything wrong in that. In OOP there are classes with only static methods, which can only be called statically. (It's non possible to do differently, since those classes aren't used to create objects.)
What Symfony/Drupal suggest is to always use dependency injection when possible. That doesn't mean classes with all static methods cannot be implemented; in fact, Drupal has classes like [`Crypt`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Component%21Utility%21Crypt.php/class/Crypt/9.3.x), which is never instantiated with `new Crypt()`. (It wouldn't make sense, since it only has static methods.)

Answer (score 0):

Dependency injection is a fairly big topic, but basically you should inject the relevant services into your class and then call the methods on them.

In drush php you can do something like:

```
$storage = $container->get('entity_type.manager')->getStorage('node');
$nodes = $storage->loadMultiple($nids);
```